# Laravel Horizon Not enough arguments (missing: "connection")

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-horizon

Before I use defaults name of supervisor-1 on config/horizon.php.
And then, I changed the name to more clear name:
supervisor-high-priority, supervisor-long-timeout, etc.

But why, supervisor.d keep call this command.

```
Starting Artisan command: horizon:supervisor
{
input: 'horizon:supervisor' 'somewebsites-webserver-production-V4ir:supervisor-1' --workers-name=default --balance=off --max-processes=10 --min-processes=1 --nice=0 --balance-cooldown=3 --balance-max-shift=1 --parent-id=17403 --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue= --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=0 --rest=0
}
```

Resulting error

```
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException
Not enough arguments (missing: "connection").
```

I already tried, to run artisan config:clear, cache:clear.
Restart the supervisor service with `sudo systemctl restart supervisor.service`

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
 
sudo supervisorctl update
 
sudo supervisorctl start horizon
```

But, supervisor keep call that supervsor-1.

Here is my supervisor configuration:

```
[program:horizon]
command=php ./artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
redirect_stderr=true
directory=/home/somewebsites/webseiten/somewebsites/current
user=manobo
stdout_logfile=/home/somewebsites/webseiten/somewebsites/current/storage/logs/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=36000
```

When I run artisan:list,
I can see the supervisor-1, that I dont have it on config/horizon.php.

I suspect, horizon cached older configuration, that can not be cleared even after running artisan config:clear.

Do I miss some steps here?
Thanks before.

**EDIT:
I found my mistake. On config/horizon. I didn't define the environments where the supervisor will be (production, staging, etc). Therefore the defaults supervisor-1 from Horizon package will be added.**

Comment: Please add the answer as an actual answer and accept it as the correct answer, otherwise this question willl stay unresolved.